# ERROR 1045 (28000) access denied cloudSQL

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'machines'@'1xx.1xx.1xx.1xx' (using password: YES)

I ran this code in the command line

```
mysql --host=1xx.1xx.1xx.1xx --user=machines --password
```

where the host IP address is obtained by requesting IPv4 address from cloudSQL.
I've tried running the same code but changing the `--host` parameter to IPv6 address provided, the result is still the same.

I've added both my IPv4 and IPv6 address to the authorize network already.
The tutorial provided at this link doesn't work for me: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-client

Comment: for some reason it is not working with command line but working with mysqlworkbench, tableplus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figure out the issue. At the user tab under access control. the host should be left as '%' instead of 'localhost' or anything else. Logging should be fine after that.